# Set active shape key using Python

Tags: python, shape-keys

I would like to set active shape key using Python. I know that I can use following code for this purpose:

```
bpy.context.active_object.active_shape_key_index = some_index
```

but, when I have several shape keys, then I don't know how to get this index from given shape key:

```
sh_key = bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["shape_key_name"]
```

There is no attribute called `index` in object `sh_key`. I tried to use `bpy.context.active_object.active_shape_key`, but this attribute is read only. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here is some quick code from the python console,

I have an active object with a number of shapekeys, "Key 1" being one, I find the index using `find(...)` then set the active_shape_key_index to this number.

`find(...)` will return -1 if a key of that name is not found.

```
>>> index = C.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.find('Key 1')
>>> index
1

>>> C.object.active_shape_key_index = index
>>>
```

Comment: At about the same time too.  Suggest using `key_blocks.get("shape_key_name")` and testing against None, can save hassles down the line for all collections in blender.

Answer (score 1):

I thing, I found solution, but it is a little bit complicated (API of vertex groups is more straightforward). You can set active shape key, when you know its name, using following code:

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
shape_key = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["shape_key_name"]
keys = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys()
shape_key_index = keys.index(shape_key.name)
obj.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_index
```